# Multiple docker using VPN

Tags: networking, docker, vpn

I have an interesting challenge, i have 3 programs that i want to run though a VPN, but i do not want the rest of the machine itself to run though the VPN.
However each of my docker containers can not individually connect to the VPN as i am maximum allowed 1 connection.

So my options so far where to merge all 3 programs into 1 docker container that is also connected via VPN.
But i where thinking if it would be possible to have a 4 docker container that would connect to the VPN and then have the 3 other containers connect though the VPN in the 4 contianer.

Comment: As for me, tasks like this are easier to be handled on host level. You'll need thoughtful docker containers network setup and proper routing configuration. If it's not really needed to do in such way (i.e. docker running VPN), another level will only introduce complexity